# Extract the English audio of video file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I like to extract the English audio stream of a video file using ffmpeg. Also, if the file doesn’t have an English audio stream, I want to extract all audio streams. Preferably with a language suffix in their names, if their languages is known.

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to submit your file to get informations regarding streams :

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.mp4
```

Then you will get all streams corresponding to your file. For example : Stream #0:4(eng) for an english subtitle

Then you can extract audio doing :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:4 -c copy audio0.mp3
```

to extract audio as an mp3 file

Comment: I can't interact with it. It needs to be automatic.